# Trying to get indexes of the files picked up by for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

```
for j in ebt:
    e.append(j*0.7)
print(e)

[1765.869, 1337.9730000000002, -2595.4530000000004, -2040.0169999999996, -419.944, 5085.668, 5747.385, 2761.479, 2329.8729999999996, -1567.055000000001, 461.71999999999895, 8140.678]
```

```
for l in e:
    if l > mean(e):
        gm.append(e.index([l]))
print(gm) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-9bc357c5b9c7> in <module>
      2 for l in e:
      3     if l > mean(e):
----> 4         gm.append(e.index([l]))
      5 print(gm)

ValueError: [1765.869] is not in list
```

What am I doing wrong? gm stands for good months, where the profit rises above the yearly mean. I'm trying to get the index of the month where this occured, but I'm getting an error instead.

Comment: Your problem is that you put l inside square brackets. It is a value in itself. You do not need to treat it as a list. Try gm.append(e.index(l)). Unfortunately index() has a runtime of O(n). Instead of doing for l in e, why don't you just do "for i in range(len(e))" and then check if e[i] > mean(e), and if it is, gm.append(i). This would not need to do a lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions, the first is more efficient, the second is more like your example.

```
for l in range(len(e)):
    if e[l] > mean(e):
        gm.append(l)
print(gm)
```

This plays off your example. Note the omission of square brackets in the index function

```
for l in e:
    if l > mean(e):
        gm.append(e.index(l))
print(gm)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just wondering, would it be possible to make gm display the names of the months instead of just numbers? Perhaps with the gm not being empty, but with names of months and the result of l being used as index?